# Issue while load CSS, Image from project folder

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

Hi I'm new to spring boot i have created project New-->Maven-->Maven project selecting simple project checkbox.once crated i have added all dependencies include jstl, but still i am not able to load my image and css into jsp its showing error below.

> `GET http://localhost:8080/image/***.jpg` 404 personList:10 GET
>   http://localhost:8080/cs /displaytag.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 personList:1 GET
>   http://localhost:8080/resources/static/images/***.jpg 404

I have tried all StackOverflow solutions which is available before like.

```
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("resources/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the entire stacktrace and also your project structure ?Have you kept all your static resources in the directory webapp/resources folder ?

Comment: src --->main-->resource-->public--
                                                      -->css
                                                      -->image
                                                              -->aaa.jpg

<img src="image/abnlogo.jpg"/>

Comment: Can you try moving css folder ouside public like src --->main-->resource-->css

Comment: tried that also

Comment: Can you share your current project structure if possible so that we get an idea about where you have kept your resources.